# Channel is not trigger in ComponentActivity

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, channel, android-viewmodel

I want to trigger an event that I defined in my base viewmodel and observe it my MainActivity. I defined channel like below

```
private val message = Channel<String>()
val messageFlow = message.receiveAsFlow()
```

Also for trying send message to channel I wrote a function like below

```
 fun triggerEvent() = viewModelScope.launch {
    message.send("MESAJ.Merhaba.BaseViewModel")
 }
```

But when I call this function in a viewmodel that based BaseViewModel, I can't observe the channel.In my MainActivity (extends ComponenctActivity and single activity) onCreate

```
    lifecycleScope.launchWhenStarted {
        viewModel.messageFlow.collect {
            Log.d("MESAJ","Mesaj geldi!!!")
        }
     }
```

I am collecting the channel in hot. But this part is not trigger. What is the problem?